# Why is Thompson Sampling considered a part of Reinforcement Learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, thompson-sampling

I often see Thompson Sampling in RL literature, however, I am not able to relate it to any of the current RL techniques. How exactly does it fit with RL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thompson Sampling (TS) is used in the context of [bandits](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/20861/2444), which is a special case of the RL problem.

You can also use TS for the full RL problem, but that can lead to **inefficient exploration**. To know more about this issue, you could read

- the section [**7.5 Reinforcement Learning in Markov Decision Processes**](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ebvr/pubs/TS_Tutorial.pdf#page=62) (p. 62) of the tutorial [A Tutorial on Thompson Sampling](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ebvr/pubs/TS_Tutorial.pdf) (2017) by Russo et al.,
- [my answer here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/24631/2444), and
- the paper [Deep Exploration via Randomized Value Functions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.07608.pdf) (2019, JMLR) by Ian Osband et al.